# Adding items to DOM in chunks

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a huge collection coming from server,  I need to create `DOM` elements for each row from the collection.

If I try to append the items to `DOM` using a for loop, my browser hangs for some time. To avoid this I tried adding the items in chunks using `setTimeout`, but until all the chunks are processed, the items are not appearing in the UI.

If I add a dubugger in the code, for each iteration I can see it appearing in the `DOM`.

I have created a sample to simulate this.

```js
var longArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var item = {
    "Name": "item" + i,
    "Id": i
  };
  longArray.push(item);
}
var chunks = _.chunk(longArray, 2);
for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(addItem(chunks[index]), 1000);
  })(i);
}

function addItem(items) {
  _.forEach(items, function(item) {
    $("<li />").html(item.Id + " : " + item.Name).appendTo("ul");
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>

<ul></ul>
```

For demo, I added 1 second delay, I am expecting before the next execution of the function, the previously added item to appear on the screen.

Currently items only appearing on the screen when all the items are processed.

Comment: Yes, I added 1 second delay for testing, but during that time I am expecting the 2 items I added to the UI to appear. Which is not happening.

Comment: Btw, `setTimeout` expects a function as first param, right now you are passing `undefined`.

Comment: I am passing function only

Comment: Maybe you do in your original code. but in your example `addItem` returns `undefined` and that is what you are passing to the `setTimeout` function. (you could set the timeout to 10 seconds and the list will still appear instantaneously, if you want to check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going tell much detail because you will get many related topics here. Just be understood that there is a logical issue in your code, basically your all setTimeouts are running all together after 1000ms. For example, change your code as follows, it would work expectedly.

```
var longArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    var item = {
      "Name": "item" + i,
      "Id": i
    };
    longArray.push(item);
 }
var chunks = _.chunk(longArray, 2);

function addItem() {
    var items = chunks.pop();
    _.forEach(items, function(item) {
      $("<li />").html(item.Id + " : " + item.Name).appendTo("ul");
    });

   if (chunks.length) {
     setTimeout(addItem, 1000);
   }
}

addItem();
```

Moreover you can use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of setTimeout, that will fix your freezing issue and will work better than setTimeout

Comment: Thanks, it helped

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `requestAnimationFrame`